# Image influences other images - wrap through function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 images that I want to position in a way, that it is independent from the window-size. I use `position: relative` declaration. But if I define the position for the first 2 images and insert the third, it destroys the position of the first two.

Is there a "wrap-through" function or something like this?

#### styles

```
  #section0 .home{
        opacity: 0;

    }
    #section0 .fecha{
        left: 130%;

        position: relative;

    }

    #section0 .pray{
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 80%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

#### function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({

                slidesNavigation: true, 
                slidesNavPosition: 'top',
                slidesColor: ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage', '5thPage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                css3: true, 

                //animation on first page
                afterRender: function(){
                        $('#section0').find('.fecha').delay(100).animate({left: '-60%', bottom: '-3%'}, 3000, 'easeOutExpo');
                        $('#section0').find('.pray').delay(100).animate({left: '0%', bottom: '28%'}, 3000, 'easeOutExpo');
                        $('#section0').find('.home').fadeTo( "slow" , 1, function() {});

                },
```

#### html

```
<div class="pray">
    <img src="CIMA/Home_pray.png" alt="Cool" style="z-index: '0', overflow: 'hidden', left: '4%', bottom: '32%'"  height="40%" width="40%"  />
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Also, be specific. "In a way" is useless to us. In what way?

Comment: Please provide us with ur current HTML , CSS , JS

Comment: If you provide us with your code, it is much more likely that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: wondering whether the answer helped...

Answer (score 0):

> that it is independent from the window-size.

Sounds like you want the elements taken out of the normal flow.

Apply `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`, this will take the images out of normal flow and they will act independent (They will no longer push each other and can overlap other elements). You can position them using the `top right bottom left` properties.

Read more about [CSS Position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

(*Yes down votes are welcome, i've a hunch this is what the OP wants, and this is just for the simplest scenario he is probably dealing with.*)

Comment: But if i put position: absolute , it doesnt give good results if i change the aspect ratio of the window, right?

Comment: You can set their height and width in `%` and it'll adjust just like any other elements in normal flow...